# Problemas com Thread no Java FX

Tags: thread, javafx

Boa noite,

Estou com problemas ao tentar implementar uma thread ao meu aplicativo, recebo sempre o mesmo erro e não sei mais como resolver.

Quando executo o aplicativo a primeira Thread entra em vigor, mas quando ela executa a segunda ele gera o erro.

Segue uma classe de exemplo:

```
package ajuda;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class AjudaController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label texto;

    private void Thread1() {

        Service service = new Service() {
            @Override
            protected Task createTask() {
                return new Task() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {

                        texto.setText("Alguma coisa");
                        Thread2();
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();
    }

    private void Thread2() {

        Service service = new Service() {
            @Override
            protected Task createTask() {
                return new Task() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object call() throws Exception {

                        texto.setText("Alguma coisa 2");
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Thread1();
    }
}
```

Toda vez que executo recebo o mesmo erro:

```
mai 24, 2018 12:14:53 AM javafx.concurrent.Service lambda$static$488
WARNING: Uncaught throwable in javafx concurrent thread pool
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at ajuda.AjudaController$2$1.call(AjudaController.java:50)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$null$493(Service.java:725)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.concurrent.Service.lambda$executeTask$494(Service.java:724)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

Qualquer alteração que você faz em elementos desenhados na tela passam pela FX Application Thread, que é apenas 1 thread. A classe service, embora interaja bem com a FX Application Thread, veja um pouco da documentação abaixo:

> A Service is a non-visual component encapsulating the information required to perform some work on one or more background threads. As part of the JavaFX UI library, the Service knows about the JavaFX Application thread and is designed to relieve the application developer from the burden of managing multithreaded code that interacts with the user interface. *As such, all of the methods and state on the Service are intended to be invoked exclusively from the JavaFX Application thread.* [...]. **However, once the Service has been initialized and started, it may only thereafter be used from the FX thread.**

Fonte: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html

O que provavelmente aconteceu foi que os dois services estavam ocupando a FX Thread e tentaram alterar o mesmo componente ao mesmo tempo. Se isso for realmente necessário, e não um erro de projeto, você pode capturar a mudança de estado usando um listener no `stateProperty()` do Service 1 para SUCCEEDED ou FAILED antes de executar o Service 2.

Comment: Entendi, mas consegue resolver jogando minha função para outra classe e a executando em um service dentro da classe principal. Meu problema agora é que não consigo dar um setText dessa forma, minha outra classe chama um método na minha classe principal que gera um setText, mas ele simplesmente não funciona...

Answer (score -2):

Use:
Platform.runLater(() -> texto.setText("Alguma coisa"));

Comment: É uma possível solução, mas considerando a API que já existe é gambiarra. A resposta que já existe é preferível por abordar o problema respeitando a API de Service que o JavaFX possui e teoricamente já tem suporte para lidar com instruções direcionadas a manipulação de GUI no _FX Application Thread_ (não conheço a API mas é o que dá a entender a resposta e a documentação citada).